# Can not pass the context parameter of a JobService to a class

Tags: java, android, android-context

I can not pass context of JobService to a location provider class. This is what I tried:

My location provider class:

```
public class Mylocation implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener {

    private Context context;

    public void Mylocation(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    //other methods of Location provider
}
```

and this is my JobService:

```
public class LocationMonitoringService extends JobService  {
    Mylocation mylocation=new Mylocation(this);
    //blah blah
    }
```

I get error on `Mylocation(this)` when I write `this`. Actually I want to pass context of JobService to the class. This is the error I get in Android Studio:

> Mylocation() in Mylocation can not be applied to
>   com.example.app.JobService

As far as I know, the `JobService` Extends `service` and service is context itslef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `void` from constructor

your constructor should be like

```
public Mylocation(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }
```

Comment: As I know `JobService` Extends `service` and `service` is **context** itslef.

Comment: try this it will defiantly help you @AliSheikhpour

Comment: I have tried and I get the same error. There should be something wrong in my class structure definition.